# Unable to send UDP packets larger than the MTU with Windows Build 1809 using C# UdpClient

Tags: c#, windows, udp, windows-10, mtu

Short version of below - we can't seem to successfully send UDP packets larger than 1472 bytes when running Build 1809 of Windows, though it worked OK in previous versions.

We have an existing C# application (really a set of applications) that runs on a local wired network that periodically sends out UDP packets to communicate status to other applications on different computers on the network.  Some of these packets are small, but some are fairly large, up close to the limit of 64k for UDP.  This application is written in C# using .NET 4.5.1 and uses the UdpClient class to broadcast and receive broadcasts.  Prior to testing with Windows 10 build 1809 / Windows Server 2019 build 1809, everything worked fine - we sent and received the larger packets without a problem.  However, starting with build 1809, it appears that we can no longer successfully send the large packets.  Here is some of the testing that we did:

System 1: Windows 10 Build 1803 (MTU is 1500)

System 2: Windows 10 Build 1809 (MTU is 1500)

I wrote a test program that sends out a small (200 bytes or so) and large (8000 bytes or so) UDP packet using UdpClient, while also listening for those packets.  Here is what happens when I send from each system:

-Send from System 1:

```
-System 1 sees both packets

-System 2 sees both packets
```

-Send from System 2:

```
 -System 1 sees only the small packet

 -System 2 sees both packets
```

This happens every single time - the large packets never arrive successfully.  Further testing revealed that the magic number was 1472 bytes. That or less worked, and more than that failed. This is why I suspect that something with fragmenting/MTU is not working correctly.  We had not seen this problem before, so I fired up Wireshark to take a look at what might be going on.  However, and this is where it gets weird, starting Wireshark on the Build 1809 system suddenly makes it able to send the packet, even if I exit Wireshark.  Rebooting the system, though, reverts it to its original state of being unable to send successfully.  I should note that I always see "Fragmented IP Protocol" for these packets in Wireshark on the receiving end of things regardless of whether they are working correctly or not.

I did some reading online and found that RDP over UDP had a major overhaul in Build 1809, but I did not see anything about UDP packets larger than the MTU having a problem, nor was I able to find anyone else reporting this particular issue.

We have made no code changes to this part of our code in a long time - it worked on Windows 7, Server 2012R2, Server 2016, and Windows 10 prior to build 1809.  Is there something new in Build 1809 that requires us to set a flag somewhere or configure something on the network adapter?  I don't know what all Wireshark does when it boots up, but it seems to "fix" things somehow, so if anyone has an idea what that might be specifically that could help as well.

Comment: This sounds like a driver issue.  See : https://wiki.wireshark.org/WinPcap. It may need an updated.  And https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/55441/what-version-of-winpcap-for-wireshark-220-for-win10.  Try NCAP

Comment: Though that is possible, we don't normally have Wireshark on our systems at all (I just put in on there to test things).  Additionally, I had one system running 1803 that worked fine, then when I installed the 1809 update, it started working poorly, so I doubt that the network drivers are the problem.

Comment: When wireshark is started it replaces the PCAP/NCAP  so that is why I think it is the driver.  You start working when wireshark is running.

Comment: I double checked the drivers for updates and they were current.  Some of the testing was done with virtual machines running either 1803 or 1809, and I see the problem on the 1809 machines but not the 1803 machines (all with the same drivers).  Also, just running Wireshark and exiting seems to "fix" things until reboot, so I am thinking it may be some setting it changes that helps (though I don't know that could be).

Comment: I did some further testing with Windows Server 2019 (everything was updated to the very latest), and I see the same problem there.  I also tried using Packet Sender (just downloaded it) and that also exhibits the problem.

Comment: The ethernet driver is part of the mother board driver set so is the motherboard the same for all PCs?  With TCP ~1500 is maximum size of a datagram and specification allow the size to vary slightly depending on implementation of specification.  Not sure if that has anything to do with issue.  I still think it is driver related and think it is with mother board driver set.

Comment: If it is driver related, then why would switching back and forth between versions 1803 and 1809 of Windows 10 in the same virtual machine with the same drivers loaded the entire time exhibit different behavior?  That makes no sense at all, which leads me to believe that something or another changed with version 1809, but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Possibly switching from a vendor driver to a standard Microsoft driver.  See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history

Comment: The broadcast service in window 10 was updated.  Not sure if it is related to issue.  Read following : https://www.howtogeek.com/325292/what-is-broadcast-dvr-server-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/

Comment: The short form of this is that disabling UDP Offload for the network adapter appears, on Windows 10 at least, to fix the problem. This was answered by someone else in a similar thread I posted on TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/965e107e-d9b0-4240-ac3f-74797c91b476/unable-to-send-udp-packets-larger-than-the-mtu-with-windows-build-1809-using-c-udpclient

Answer (score 1):

I ended up contacting Microsoft about this early last year and pushed until they admitted it was an issue. The issue affects 1809, 1903, 1909, 2004, and 20H2. They have finally released the fix publicly in the "2021-03 Cumulative Update for Windows 10". Fixes are available for 1903 and higher. I have confirmed this update does indeed fix the issue for us.

See: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5001649

It is not mentioned specifically in this KB anywhere that I can find, but this is the version the support person gave me and it is fixed after applying this update.

Comment: Thanks for pushing Microsoft on this and finding the fix.  I will pass this along to out team.

Comment: @Brian yeah no problem this was a blocker for us. Please accept my answer if this update solved it for you.